# Get existing gorilla sessions

Tags: http, session, go, gorilla

I am trying to set a gorilla session and then retreive the value again. I am doing the following just as a test.

```
//create session and store in http Cookies
session, err := store.Get(req, "session")
if err != nil {
    errCode = http.StatusInternalServerError
    return
}

//save a value
session.Values["user_id"] = userTuple.UserId
err = session.Save(req, w)
if err != nil {
    errCode = http.StatusInternalServerError
    return
}

//try to get the same session that was just created
nr := http.Request{Header: w.Header()}
session, err = store.Get(&nr, "session")
if err != nil {
    errCode = http.StatusInternalServerError
    return
} else if session.IsNew {
    log.Println("New session created instead of old one.")
}
```

This is a snippet out of a larger HTTP handler. But the relavent parts are posted and the the second call to `store.Get()` is not returning an existing session, but a brand new one. Hence, when the handler this code is in is executed, the log statements is printed to console.

Why am I getting a new session in this case instead of the one I had already created  and saved?

Comment: What kind of store are you using?

Comment: No this is different code. I posted incorrectly code the first time. Same question, different problem.

Comment: Im using a CookieStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like I already answered this question.  You are misusing this pkg.  Behind the scenes the [context](https://github.com/gorilla/context) package is used to store state for a request, by creating a new, incomplete http.Request, the context package returns an empty state with no session info.

check out this [code](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/sessions.go#L121) to see what i'm talking about.

Comment: thanks for the help. the incomplete response doesn't work for some reason that I am still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The following code won't work because the actual season values are saved inside the cookie that is written to `ResponseWriter`, copying:

```
nr := http.Request{Header: w.Header()}
session, err = store.Get(&nr, "session")
```

The code for saving is https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/store.go#L101

And it stores season id based on the request pointer for some odd reason, check https://github.com/gorilla/context/blob/master/context.go#L31.

You'd have to reload the page to access the new cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with gorilla/sessions, but with how you're constructing that request struct.

When you call `session.Save(r, w)`, `w.Header()` will now contain a map like the following:

```
map[string][]string{
  // ...
  "Set-Cookie": []string{/* ... */}
  // ...
}
```

You should replace that `Set-Cookie` header with a `Cookie` header - otherwise, gorilla/sessions won't see any cookies in the request, and will assume that the request didn't have a session cookie.

But yeah, like @OneOfOne mentioned, you'd usually just call `http.Redirect` and have the browser do that `Set-Cookie`-`Cookie` replacement for you.